# why the push method works in this Queue using javascrip

Tags: javascript, linked-list

can someone please explain to how push(val) method works? I can't understand the logic. I don't know how this works, why it works.

```
class Node {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }
};

class Queue {
    constructor() {
        this.first = null;
        this.last = null;
        this.length = 0;
    }

    push(val) {
        const temp = new Node(val)
        if(this.last === null) {
            this.first = temp
            this.last = temp
        } else {
            this.last.next = temp
            this.last = temp
        }
        this.length++;
        console.log(this)
    }
}

const queue = new Queue();
queue.push('Joy');
queue.push('Matt');
queue.push('Pavel');
```

Comment: Have a look here -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Answer (score 0):

This is a linked list:

[image]

So, initially, first (Head in the image) and last elements are null:

```
this.first = null;
this.last = null;
this.length = 0;
```

At this point, both are pointing to null.

If you add a new element, and if `last` is null, it knows that this is the initial state, which means, no element in the queue, so add the very first element to the queue and make `first` and `last` point to the same object, because there's only one at this point:

```
if(this.last === null) {
    this.first = temp
    this.last = temp
}
```

If you add another element, first check if there's any element in the queue (by checking the validity of `last`) and if there is, add it to the end of the queue by:

```
else {
    this.last.next = temp
    this.last = temp
}
```

To explain it further, it does the following:

- `this.last` is pointing to the last element of the queue (as of before adding the new element), so updates its `next` property to point to the new element.
- Then, update `this.last` to point to the new last element, which is being added.
- Also, note that at this point, its `next` pointer is pointing to `null`.

Comment: but I don't know why this.first is gonna equal Joy => Matt => Pavel

Comment: `this.first` will always be equal to `Joy`.